# Inserting shell script variable into xml

Tags: xml, shell, sh

I would like to use a shell script variable to add it to the xml code, but I can't find the way how to do it.

```
variable="1234"
-X '<delete_target target_id="iwantvariablehere"/>'
```

Comment: `"<delete_target target_id=\"$variable\"/>"` ... ? Or what is your problem?

Comment: Thanks you very much, I was not sure what is the problem, but now works. I didn't know how to use the variable, so I suspected it to be the source of the problem, but looks like I used ' instead of " and that was it. I don't know why, but if I simply wrote the numbers inside it also worked with the '-marks. So thanks you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed variables in double-quoted stings, like so:

```
"<delete_target target_id=\"$variable\"/>"
```

Embedding variables will *not* work if you use single-quoted strings!

Some more explanation can be found at (for example) http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/variables-tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
sed -i 's/STRING_TO_REPLACE/'"${VARIABLE}"'/' dir/subdir/myfile.xml
```

Any occurrence of STRING_TO_REPLACE will become the value of VARIABLE.

Proceed with caution as the xml file will be overwritten